# How to make a PHP based script for finding UK addresses by entering postcode?

Tags: php, google-maps

I've almost looked everywhere but nothing found, so my only hope would be here though! :(

I want to make a PHP based script for finding UK address by entering postcode, so a list would show with a number of houses' numbers!

Any idea how I could do that, I know that I must use API, even though I search for Google Maps API for this, but nothing found whatsoever!

Any idea?

I need this particular script for an additional registration script which allows uk residents to be able to register for a specific reason, so please help if you know where I could get started!

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: you want all the addresses that belong to a post code? that is quite a valuable information, can be used by spammers and local businesses :)

Comment: The postcode database is a licensed database - available from the post office -> http://www.royalmail.com/marketing-services/address-management-unit/address-data-products

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally these systems utilise the [Royal Mail PAF database](http://www.royalmail.com/marketing-services/address-management-unit/address-data-products/postcode-address-file-paf), but this does cost quite a lot of money.

There are services out there that offer X amount of requests for a set price (or a monthly price), so if buying the full thing isn't an option then you could have a look into one of those services.

It is something you are going to need to spend money on though - it's not a service that anyone (that I've ever found) is offering for free.

I don't think this is something you can get out of Google maps either.

Comment: Thanks for your very useful information! To be honest I don't know what other solutions I could go for! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yeah, sorry I couldn't bring you better news (i.e. a free solution), but sadly Royal Mail don't give this information out for free! If it's not going to be a high usage thing then one of the Royal Mail's resellers might be a good idea to look into, as said before - these are usually either monthly/yearly fees, or charged per request. http://www.poweredbypaf.com/supplier-search/search-results/

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are quite a few projects working on this dataset - just look at e.g. http://www.freethepostcode.org/ and the associated projects.

Comment: I live in the US, but I love the ideals of this project. I hope it gets a huge following.

Comment: Cool! Thanks, but it sounds that I won't be able to implement this in my script as it costs! This is a good idea but nevertheless cannot yet be used in any script! Right! So what other alternative methods could I go for that would be free! Thanks

Comment: I don't get your problem - you want to have this list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postcode_districts_in_the_United_Kingdom and search in it, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch the postcode latitude and longitude using google api:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=(POSTCODE HERE)&sensor=false
```

then using the lat and long from that you can get the street name

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=(LAT),(LNG)&sensor=false
```

see reference here:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: Nice :) Thank you... it would be very useful for future projects

Answer (score 0):

We can get all UK addresses by postal code with api.getaddress.io API. You can found an example on https://usingphp.com/post/how-to-get-all-uk-addresses-by-postal-code